# Model decimal validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am using MVC 4, EF, and .NET 4.0.

I have a model with the following field:

```
[Display(Name = "Price")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[Range(0,100)]
public decimal Price{ get; set; }
```

I display it in a textbox in my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Price)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Price)
```

If I type 0.3 in the Price textbox, validation passes. However if I type .3 in (or any number that begins with a decimal), client-side validation fails and the error "The field Price must be a number." is displayed.

How can I allow users to enter a number that begins with a decimal without the error displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe updating jQuery to the latest version as Jamie Dixon suggested would fix the problem. However, I am not able to update jQuery in my application at this time.

As a work around, I added a Javascript function that adds a preceding zero to any number beginning with a decimal.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Price').keydown(function () {
        FixDecimal($('#Price'))
    });

    function FixDecimal(obj) {
       var val = obj.val();
       val = val.replace('$', '');
       if (val.indexOf('.', 0) == 0) val = '0' + val;

       obj.val(val);
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a value like this in a `decimal` you'll need to use the `M` suffix to create a literal of the decimal type.

`decimal d = .3; // Won't compile`

`decimal d = .3M; // Will compile`

This is because `.3` is not a `decimal`, it's a `double`. The following would compile without requiring any suffix:

`double dbl = .3;`

Comment: I changed the field to `public double Price{ get; set; }` and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: What client side validation are you using?

Comment: I believe whatever is built in with MVC. Not using anything additional.

Comment: EditorFor still seems to have the same problem.

Comment: From what i've read, this is an issue with the ways jQuery validate does its number validation. It apparently fixed in the latest version so I'd suggest you get that and try.